# How do I add a whole folder to Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm currently trying Visual Studio Team Services, and I want to check in a whole folder containing code and more subfolders. I'm in the CODE->EXPLORER tab and when I right-click on the right side (the main area), a context menu appears where there is a menuitem Add. So, I tried adding an existing item, however, it won't let me put in folders. I tried then dragging the whole folder in the content area but it says error. How do I add folders in source control?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't believe its possible to add folders from VSTS (formerly VSO) but you could connect to VSTS via VisualStudio and uses the Source Control Explorer to add folders.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can create new folder directly in Visual Studio Team Services website using the Folder Management extension. Follow this steps:

1. Login to your VSTS account, f.e. https://{account}.visualstudio.com
2. In the top of website choose Browse Marketplace

[image: Go to the Marketplace]

3. Search extension **Folder management** or visit direct [this URL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.FolderManagement) of extension
4. Install the extension and choose an account to associate

[image: Install Folder Management extension]

5. Go back to VSTS account and choose CODE in main menu

Now you can create new folder directly:

[image: Create new folder in VSTS]

Comment: great idea, unfortunately doesn't seem to be operational, at least on our project... installed fine... but just locks up when selected

Comment: This solution worked for me on {me}.visualstudio.com in April of 2017. However, the extension does not permit adding a folder by dragging and dropping the folder into the Code pane. It displays the error "Failed to read file {folder name}".

Comment: Bizarre this solution works through the web browser but trying in Visual Studio with Solution Explorer New Folder is greyed out. Even tried by ensuring all pending changes have been checked in.

Answer (score 4):

Use Visual Studio/Team Explorer.  Map to a local folder, then just use windows explorer to copy/paste your folder/files into your mapped folder.  In Team Explorer/VS it will pick up all the added files and you can check them all in in one operation.

Comment: Not all team members have Visual Studio. BA's and managers, who do not code, are not in need of wasting a VS license on, but they do need to create documentation for the project, and sometimes, yes, create a folder. WOW, what an oversight on Microsoft's part.