# No add folder option in tfs 2015 code explorer pane

Tags: tfs-2015

I did not find Add folder option in right pane of code explorer in tfs 2015. But there is Add Files option and I can add files to any folder in the code exploerr. Please refer to the screenshot below. Did anyone have same issue?

[image: add folder option not available in tfs 2015 code explorer]

Answer (score 1):

Download and install [Folder Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.FolderManagement) extension to your TFS collection, you will be able to create folder from left panel:

[image]

Comment: I tried to upload from Web Access Extensions page. Ours is TFS 2015 Update 1. But I am getting following error: "Extension manifest file format is invalid." Any idea?

Comment: @sangam Cannot see this error at my side. Did you upload it from "Legacy Extensions" panel? This extension is not a legacy extension, you need to upload it from "Browse for extensions\Manage Extensions\Upload new extension".

Comment: Yes, I found I was doing from wrong place.But now even with administrator login having permission "Edit instance-level information" enabled, I am not seeing that "small marketplace icon" at the top right of my tfs web page. Is there I am missing? Appreciating your help.

Comment: Eddie, is it that on-premise TFS server we have installed is unable to browse the market place? Is it available on microsoft hosted TFS only?

Comment: @sangam Upgrade your TFS server to the latest Update 4 and then try again.

Comment: Never mind, I found the workaround in which I can do the commit directly from git client - gitbash in my case. This way I am able to create folders in the tfs code repo. I will give a try with update 4 also as you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, you are using Git repo in TFS. It's not a issue, it's **by designed**.

You could not add folders in remote repo directly. The add files is more like upload file. If you want to add folders, suggest you directly push your local repo to remote repo.

Also take a look at this similar question: [How do I add a whole folder to Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481676/how-do-i-add-a-whole-folder-to-visual-studio-team-services-was-tfs-online)